# Pipelink: A Cat for jkittykitkat

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

**Rules of Pipelink**:

1. Draw a loop through the centers of all cells.
2. Two perpendicular line segments may intersect (cross) each other, but not turn at their intersection or otherwise overlap.
3. Clues show how the loop crosses through the cell it’s in.

---

This is the first time I set a Pipelink. I tried to draw a cat, a tribute to the person who introduced and guided me about the genre, [jkittykitkat](https://jkpuzzles.wordpress.com/), :3

The standard Pipelink rules apply.

[image]

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there's 2 separate pipes or just 1 long pipe that crosses?

Comment: @Stevo There is only 1 long pipe that can cross. The second rule states that if the pipe is crossing, both segments must be straight.

Comment: Got it now. _opening puzzlink_

Comment: Pain. Just solved it and deleted half my solve path in the process of writing the answer...

Comment: [Penpa link](https://git.io/JKwDX) for interested solvers. Recommend the "Line\Middle" tool for solving.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a very nice puzzle made by:

> [image: athin solution]

This is the solve process:

> First draw some necessary connections and impossibilities:
>
>  [image: step 1]
>
>  Fill in the top left corner, and some necessary connections:
>
>  [image: step 2]
>
>  Take some free corner areas:
>
>  [image: step 3]
>
>  Fill in some more necessary connections and corner areas:
>
>  [image: step 4]
>
>  Fill in the top-right corner and flesh out the top and top-right areas:
>
>  [image: step 5]
>
>  Realize that covering the bottom left leaves a square underneath the up-heading line uncovered:
>
>  [image: step 6]
>
>  So cross over it and continue:
>
>  [image: step 7]
>
>  See that going up on the right side will either loop prematurely or block the incoming top-loop on the bottom center:
>
>  [image: step 8]
>
>  So go left instead and create a corner that you fill in:
>
>  [image: step 9]
>
>  Finish off the bottom right:
>
>  [image: step 10]
>
>  Fill in some more required connections:
>
>  [image: step 11]
>
>  Fill in some more required connections and deal with corners:
>
>  [image: step 12]
>
>  Prevent looping too early on the top right:
>
>  [image: step 13]
>
>  Use the only out to create a corner:
>
>  [image: step 14]
>
>  Realize the line below the highlighted square can't go down without leaving the line above the highlighted square hanging:
>
>  [image: step 15]
>
>  Fill in some impossibilities:
>
>  [image: step 16]
>
>  Use the created corner and fill in another corner:
>
>  [image: step 17]
>
>  Complete the cross:
>
>  [image: step 18]
>
>  We can try going left at the boxed space, but it forces two separate closed loops to form:
>
>  [image: step 19]
>
>  So, we instead go right and fill in a corner:
>
>  [image: step 20]
>
>  We continue extending on the left side:
>
>  [image: step 21]
>
>  Repeat until we are nearly finished, with only one line remaining:
>
>  [image: step 22]
>
>  Which we promptly fill in:
>
>  [image: step 23]

The next step is to:

> Go celebrate a puzzle well solved :)

Comment: Beautiful write-up! Thanks for your care, Avi!

Comment: Great job and well done! Lol at the pattern on the first spoiler XD